# Double-click on ListBox within DataGridTemplateColumn to open window - opens underneath

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have ListBoxes defined in a DataTemplateColumn:

```
<Window x:Class="DoubleclickTest.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataGrid Name="dg" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox Loaded="ListBox_Loaded" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

and I want to open a new window on double-clicking the listbox:

```
public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    dg.ItemsSource = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
}

private void ListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ((ListBox)sender).ItemsSource=Enumerable.Range(1,5);
}

private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    e.Handled = true;
    var win = new MainWindow();
    win.Show();
    //Neither of these help:
    //win.Activate();
    //win.Focus();
}
```

The new window opens underneath the current window.

How can I have the new window open over the current window (without using `ShowDialog`)?

**Update**

Using an `ItemsControl` instead of a `ListBox` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .NET 4.5:

```
private async void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    e.Handled = true;
    await Task.Delay(20);
    var win = new MainWindow();
    win.Show();
}
```

This is still a bit of a hack to work around the issue, but if there are no better solutions I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

That was a weird behavior but the following method will help:

```
<Window ... Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Use a timer to activate the window:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(10);
    t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
    t.Start();
}

void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Timer).Stop();
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        this.Activate();
        this.Focus();
    });
}
```

The used timer is system timer:

```
using System.Timers;
```

Comment: How about creating the timer (and adding a handler to open the window on a delay) within the double-click handler?

Comment: That would work however I tested my code and it's working not only for the first time.